# using parcel to pull in typescript dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, bootstrap-4, parceljs

I'm using parcel to process typescript for a webextension.
JQuery and its type definitions are installed via npm.
At the top of my typescript file I have:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import "bootstrap";
```

But at runtime, Chrome complains that jquery is not defined.
A minimal example to reproduce the problem is on git: https://github.com/lhk/parcel_jquery_bug_demo

```
git clone https://github.com/lhk/parcel_jquery_bug_demo
cd parcel_jquery_bug_demo
npm install
parcel build src/manifest.json
```

Now you can open chrome and load the dist folder

The git repo contains:

**src/manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "pc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "none",
  "author": "",
  "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": [
         "./content/index.ts"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**src/content/index.ts**

```
import $ from "jquery";
import "bootstrap";

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

**./package.json**

```
{
  "name": "pc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-plugin-web-extension": "^1.4.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.10",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

After you loaded the extension in chrome, you can load any website.
The error message is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I'm using:

- Parcel 1.10.1
- Node   v8.12.0
- npm 6.4.1
- ubuntu 18.04.1 64bit
- chrome 70

I think this problem is related to the import of bootstrap. The following code works:

```
import $ from "jquery";

//import "bootstrap";

$(function () {
  //$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').click(function(){});
});
```

So the dependency of my typescript code is actually handled by parcel. But bootstrap also needs jQuery and that is somehow not satisfied.

Comment: You are right. Bootstrap is depending on the presence of a global that jquery doesn't create when it is loaded in a module aware environment

Comment: Yup, that's an incredibly helpful tip (no irony here). Someone on the parcel issue tracker told me the same thing. You can make it work by manually adding jQuery to window. But that's pretty hacky. It would be nice if npm and parcel could pick this up somehow. Is there a cleaner way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parcel actually takes no part in the issue, it is mostly that jQuery/Bootstrap relies on the `$` and `jQuery` function being exposed in the global scope.

This is fairly simple to archive by doing the following (for JS only, since TS will complain about window not having the property `$` and `jQuery`):

```
import jquery from "jquery";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery;
import "bootstrap";
```

**But since you're using TypeScript** you will need to do more in order to get the linting and intellisense support working too.

1. Install the TypeScript definition file `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery @types/bootstrap`
2. use `import * as $ from 'jquery';` to import it.
3. Configure the libs for the DOM api since they are not enable by default for TypeScript, this will allow you to use a proper `window` and `document` but you 
   need to change `window` to `(<any> window)`

   > tsconfig.json

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       //...
       "lib": ["dom"],
       //...
     },
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I added a babel plugin ([babel-plugin-auto-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-auto-import)) with this .babelrc

```
  {
    "plugins": [[
      "auto-import", {
        "declarations": [
          { "anonymous": ["jQuery"], "path": "jquery" }
        ]
      }
    ]]
  }
```

Everything seems to be working.

New package.json

```
{
  "name": "pc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-plugin-auto-import": "^0.9.3",
    "parcel-plugin-web-extension": "^1.4.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.10",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```